# NSUserDefaults removePersistentDomainForName crash issue

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am getting this crash as below when I am trying to save the UserDefaults value.

OS Version:      **Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)**

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)

Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000080000018

Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name: objectForKey:

objc[240]: GC: forcing GC OFF because OBJC_DISABLE_GC is set

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

0   libobjc.A.dylib   0x00007fff91dcc5d0 objc_msgSend_vtable8 + 16

Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11

**Scenario**

When user logs in to my application in System Preferences pane, app receives few settings from a server which is updated to NSMutableDictionary. 
After updating the dictionary, I set the the values for the domain using below code,

```
    - (void) saveUserDefaults;
{
    // Validate NSMutableDictionary instance only contains valid plist objects
    [self CheckDictionary:profileDefaults];
    NSLog(@"saveUserDefaults:  %@", profileDefaults);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] bundleIdentifier]];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setPersistentDomain:profileDefaults forName:[[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] bundleIdentifier]];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

}
```

The crash happens if I quit the System Preferences app, post successful login. This happens because I call this saveUserDefaults() function whenever i get an NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification. Just before the crash I print the contents of NSMutableDictionary and all key-value pairs are fine. I even added code to check if NSMutableDictionary that i am saving is in proper format but doesn't help prevent crash

```
    - (void) CheckDictionary:(id)plist
{
    if (![NSPropertyListSerialization
          propertyList: plist
          isValidForFormat: kCFPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0])
    {
        NSLog(@"Dictionary profileDefaults not in proper format");
    }
}
```

Also this crash happens only once during login and when the System preferences recovers and launched again, even when I quit the System Preferences app, no crash is seen. 
What does this mean :

```
Application Specific Information: objc_msgSend() selector name: objectForKey:
```

I am unable to fix this issue and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line  and check:-

```
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removePersistentDomainForName:[[NSBundle bundleForClass: [self class]] bundleIdentifier]];
```

Comment: I removed that line and checked. Worked fine without crash Mountain Lion 10.8.5 but with an unrecognised selector warning in system.log. It still crashes on Mavericks 10.9.1. Can you please explain the reason to remove this line as well.

Comment: Ohk then change this code and use setObject forKey method of NSUserDefault and check.

Comment: I didn't get that. I perform setObject forKey inside a function where i get the response from the server and at the end call my function saveUserDefaults().